# change last 10 characters of the base (not extension) of multiple files

Tags: files, rename, command

I have many files of different lengths but the same extension and I have tried many commands to rename all of them at once.

Is it possible to change only the last 10 characters of the base of all filenames? 
The 10 last characters are always the same.

For example :

```
img(12345678).txt
test(12345678).txt 
download(12345678).txt
upload(12345678).txt
```

I want to replace `(12345678)` with `abcdefghij`

Comment: Can you get more help , how to do this ?

Comment: If you wanted to know **how** to do this, you should not just have asked whether it is possible. Give a few examples, by **updating your post**  of file names before and after. Make sure it is clear if the 10 last characters on the original files are always the same or not. If they are not make sure to include what happens if the file name parts before them are different. And while you update your post change the question so the answer cannot be a simple Yes/No (which makes for a non-useful question for this site which is probably the cause for the down votes).

Comment: did you want it to work for your exact example or for any combination of characters in the filename? The solutions below expect (12345678) to be in the filename for them to work (I think).

Comment: @dakka Good point. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two Linux commands called `rename` that are commonly available in distributions. I prefer the perl-based rename, as it's more powerful. You can check which one you have using `$ prename --version`.

If you have the perl-based rename,

```
$ rename --version
perl-rename 1.9
$ rename 's/\(12345678\)/abcdefghij/' *.txt
```

If you want to check it first with a dry run, use the `-n` flag.

If you have the other rename,

```
$ rename --version
rename from util-linux 2.26.2
$ rename '(12345678)' abcdefghij *.txt
```

### To remove the last 10 characters before `.txt` generally

If the characters are not always the same, you can use this in the general case.

For perl-based rename,

```
rename 's/.{10}\.txt\Z/abcdefghij.txt/' *.txt -n
```

For the other rename, I'm not sure if it's possible.

Comment: If you're globbing only `.txt` files, you can shorten the last pattern to `.{10}\.` and the last replacement to `abcdefghij.`

Comment: @kos That won't work if there is another `.` in the filename, with at least ten characters preceding, e.g. `foobarfoobar.foo(12345678).txt`. However, I've just realised I need to anchor the `txt` too. I'll re-edit.

Comment: Yeah, if that's a concern you'd rather not

Comment: @kos I just figure that it's better to cover all edge cases, if it's not much more effort to code.

Comment: It's probably better how you do it. In more complex cases I have the habit of just strictly covering the example tough, because covering *every* edge case would be *way* more extensive and, to be honest, those should be up to OP to be pointed out. However in this case I agree it was not much of an effort

Answer (score 3):

Try this.  If happy with the proposed moves, remove the `echo` and rerun.

```
$ ls
download(12345678).txt  img(12345678).txt  upload(12345678).txt
$ for F in *; do echo mv "$F" "${F/(12345678)/abcdefghij}"; done
mv download(12345678).txt downloadabcdefghij.txt
mv img(12345678).txt imgabcdefghij.txt
mv upload(12345678).txt uploadabcdefghij.txt
$
```

Comment: nothing changed ..

Comment: You should quote your variables, otherwise this would fail for files with whitespace in their name.

Comment: i know this  , it wouldn't fail ..

Comment: respond As you've example but nothing changed finally

Comment: @1001dlc Sorry, the message was for the author.

Comment: @1001dlc please don't be so impatient. Did you try the `for` loop? Did you then remove the `echo` to run it for real, as instructed? If so, you are going to need to provide some feedback to help us understand why it didn't work for you

Comment: @1001dlc : suspect you didn't remove the `echo`. Anyway, appears you have now found a solution to the problem, all good.

Answer (score 2):

You can just do this in `bash`/`dash`/`zsh`, no need to revert to utilities that might not be installed. In `bash`:

```
for x in *"(12345678).txt"; do mv "$x" "${x%(12345678).txt}"abcdefghij.txt; done
```

the `$x%pattern` is for removing matchin suffices. `From man bash`:

```
   ${parameter%word}
   ${parameter%%word}
          Remove matching suffix pattern.  The word is expanded to produce
          a pattern just as in pathname expansion.  If the pattern matches
          a  trailing portion of the expanded value of parameter, then the
          result of the expansion is the expanded value of parameter  with
          the  shortest  matching  pattern (the ``%'' case) or the longest
          matching pattern (the ``%%'' case) deleted.  If parameter  is  @
          or  *,  the  pattern  removal operation is applied to each posi‐
          tional parameter in turn, and the  expansion  is  the  resultant
          list.   If  parameter is an array variable subscripted with @ or
          *, the pattern removal operation is applied to  each  member  of
          the array in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 ls |  awk '{printf "mv %s %s\n",$0,gsub("(12345678)","abcedfgh" );}' | bash
```

Comment: Probably `find` with `-exec` or `-execdir` is more robust than piping from `ls`. What about files with newlines in their name? Also, doesn't the `awk` part fail for files with whitespace in their name?

Comment: there must be some kind of macros, every time someone pipe ls, another folk in U&L came and say "what about file with newline, pipe symbol, & and ; in their names ? "

Comment: That's because piping `ls` is not a very robust concept. Why wouldn't you just use `find`?

Comment: Indeed those are rare cases and maybe even 99% of the time it's safe to just parse `ls`, but maybe it's also worth a quick mention of the fact that such commands could break on such characters?